# Access Main Thread uncommited data in worker thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, transactions

I am running into one issue with the code I am working on. The task is I get a file with Purchase Order details. The purchase order has individual items  and each item has its delivery schedule. The creation of PO is atomic (all or nothing). So all these is running under one transaction.

I already have following methods for the sub tasks. 
1. CreatePO 
2. CreateItem 
3. AddDeliveryScheduleToItem(ItemId).

When I execute all this in sequential fashion everything works fine. Sequential fashion means first I create PO.  Second I create all Items under PO one by one.  Third I add delivery schedule to each line item one by one. Here the Transaction start before creating the PO and commit after the delivery schedule is added to all items. If any error the app roll back the transaction.

While adding delivery schedule to item I do retrieve the Item record from database to retrieve the schedule details thats how current code is written.

So far so good.

Now adding delivery schdule is time consuming task so we decided to add threading and run the adding delivery schedule in parallel. So I created a method called AddDeliveryScheduleInThread() and call AddDeliveryScheduleToItem(ItemId) within this method.

Using ThreadPool I fire AddDeliveryScheduleInThread()  in parallel. Now issue arise when AddDeliveryScheduleToItem(ItemId) tries to retrieve the Item record based on item id. Remember we created this item in main thread in transaction but it is not commited yet.

The code currently using Spring.NET transaction and I can't find much help over there.

How to resolve this issue ? Please help me.

I am open to not using the Spring.NET transaction.  I am looking into Dependable Transaction and Commitable Transaction right now if that can help.

Thanks

Comment: "Now adding delivery schdule is time consuming task" - could you explain?

Comment: There are some caclulcation and other thing involved than just plain insert. So its our first candidate to process in parallel to process the whole transaction quicker. The main problem is in multithreaded mode the Item created in main thread is not available in worker thread which add the schedule to item.

Comment: Why not just run the whole song and dance on a thread?

Comment: It is working fine on single thread but performance is slow. With multi thread we can improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

> AddDeliveryScheduleToItem(ItemId)
>   tries to retrieve the Item record
>   based on item id. Remember we created
>   this item in main thread in
>   transaction but it is not commited
>   yet.

I can think of only two options.

1) Don't AddDeliveryScheduleToItem(ItemId) until the transaction is committed.

2) Don't put AddDeliveryScheduleToItem(ItemId)  on another thread but instead make it very fast so you don't have to put it on another thread.

The easy way to make 2 very fast is to simply add it to a queue rather than do the whole process. Have another process looking at that queue to see if there a new items to Schedule and then schedule do the long running bit.

Comment: Thanks Conard for you suggestion but I don't think I can go with it. 1 If I need to make sure that whole transaction is atomic if there is failaure while adding delivery schedule I want to roll back tran. This is requirements because we don't want to modify the file we are trying to process. For your suggestion 2 we want to speed up the process by running them in parallel becaus one item can have hundered of schedules and one po can have tens or may be hundreds of items.

Comment: @Henry. So if one of the items in a PO can't be scheduled you want to roll back the whole process?

Comment: yes that is correct. B/c user does not want to hand update the file.